# Socket code refusing localhost connection on Pi, not on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am experiencing issues regarding the c socket system. My code is simple, it opens up a socket on the localhost on port 5800 and writes a 5 letter string. However, this code works on a Linux PC (Linux Lite) but fails on a pi, also I'm using the Raspian Operative System on the Raspberry PI.

I am using g++ for both compilers, no compiler options

My minimal example is as follows:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    /*
    Initialize the socket connection
    */
    const int port = 5800;
    const char* ip = "127.0.0.1";   

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (-1 == sock) {
        perror("socket() failed");
        assert(0 && "socket() failed");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    memset(&name, 0, sizeof(name));
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(name.sin_addr));

    if (-1 == connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&name, sizeof(name))) {
        perror("connecting stream socket"); 
        assert(0 && "connect() failed");
    }

    write(sock, "Hello", 6);
    return 0;
}
```

All of this is fine and dandy. Compiles with no issues whatsoever. On Linux everything works swimmingly. Here is an image of the code communicating successfully with a netcat server:

[image: Socket program successfully talking to a netcat server]

The program sends the expected string to netcat. However, compiling this code on a fresh pi and running it in the same scenario as above leads to the following terminal output:

On the client end:

```
connecting stream socket: Connection refused
build: vid.cpp:61: int main(int, char**): Assertation \`0 && connect() 
failed.
Aborted
```

On the server end (the netcat "nc -l localhost 5800"), no output is produced.

The port that I am using works correctly. (I tested with netcat) No other settings are different on the pi, the source code is the exact same on the pi and the Linux machine. The PI is fresh out of the box, no settings altered whatsoever.

My question is, what factors may be contributing to the failure of my program on the raspberry pi, and what might I do to resolve them? Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The port 5800 is not blocked on the raspberry pi. I can successfully connect a netcat server and client together on localhost 5800. My issue is, my code connects to the netcat server on my Linux PC, but not the netcat server on the pi.

Comment: Make sure you're actually running the server on the pi and not on your PC by mistake.

Comment: I am running both of the servers on the localhost, (so the pi server is on the pi and the pc server is running on the pc). The PC and the Pi are not even on the same network.

Comment: Do: `perror(strerror(errno))` and see if it prints anything? Try running with `sudo`?

Comment: `perror(strerror(errno))` outputs: Connection refused. Same results with sudo.

Comment: @RazeLighter777 If you are running the server on your PC and running the client on the pi and the client is connecting to localhost, it will try to connect to the pi. Therefore the server (netcat) needs to be listening on the pi as well.

Comment: @immibis The pi is trying to connect to the netcat server on the pi, and the PC is trying to connect to the netcat server on the PC. The Pi has nothing to do with the PC, they aren't even on the same network.

Comment: @RazeLighter777; Try running: https://pastebin.com/ekjAvYfK then run your original code right after. If the above code prints "Hello" then the error is not in your code, but elsewhere..

Comment: @Brandon When I connect my client to your server, it exits without printing anything. When I stepped through with GDB, res was equal to 0 and it broke out of the loop at line 53.

Comment: @Brandon `perror()` already prints `strerror(errno)`. The argument is a descriptive string to identify where it was printed from. Supplying the error string as the argument is pointless.

Comment: @OP How are you running `netcat` on the Pi?

Comment: You should run your program and if it fails, immediately run netcat in the same terminal to test the connection. Please show output of this sequence.

Comment: Make sure the firewall on the pi isnt blocking the port you want to get at.

Comment: @EJP The command for the netcat server on the pi is nc -l localhost 5800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your client is pointing to localhost**, how would you connect to another device if you are pointing to localhost?

As for **Connection Refused** output, you should check if there is a **Firewall** and also **if you are on the same network**... (if you werent connecting to a listenting port on localhost and you were ***trying to connect to another device***).

But you said that you were connecting to a netcat server on localhost, you should check if netcat is being well used... why dont you post the output of the verbose -v?

When writting a socket **client** on the **C** language (**UNIX** networking implementation), you need the following libs...
**sys/socket.h** for the **socket**, **connect**, **send**, **recv** and **close** functions.

You are using **netinet/in.h** and **arpa/inet.h** for **sockaddr_in**, this structure is used for defining the address for the socket... also, this structure is part of the old UNIX networking implementation.

**netdb.h** for the **addrinfo** structure (which you should be using instead of sockaddr_in because its overall easier to use and also, *its IP version agnostic*, **sockaddr_in** works in IPv4, with this said, using addrinfo is part of the newer implementation you should be using as it works in both IPv4 and IPv6)...

Also... you are using write(), which is good as you are writting into a file descriptor (which in this case is the socket), but the send() function would be more apropiate.

This was my **client** implementation... I used it on both Android as a compiled binary and in my Archlinux x86_64 PC.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h> // for memset()

#define PORT "1234"
#define IP "127.0.0.1"

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;

    getaddrinfo(IP, PORT, &hints, &res);

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_flags);

    connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

The next one is my **server** implementation.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT "7654"

int main(void){
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res);

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    listen(sockfd, 1);

    struct sockaddr_in c_addr;
    socklen_t c_addrlen = sizeof(c_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &c_addr, &c_addrlen);

    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RazeLighter777 I'm using gcc and its working just fine, are you just trying to connect on a netcat or something else?

Comment: @RazeLighter777 consider using ltrace or strace. Those are tools really easy to use that tell you what the program's output is and what happens on runtime (syscall and functions), like a debugger but easier to use. In your case would be really useful.